# How can I stop an setTimeout after one run?

Tags: javascript

I have this looping countdown, but I want it to run from 7 to 4 and stay at 4 without looping. So 4 will stay and be visible and nothing will happen after that.

```
<div id="dcontent" style="width:100%; background-color: #E2E2FC; padding-left: 5px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var mycontent = new Array()
  mycontent[0] = 'Jetzt schnell sein! Nur noch 7 Artikel verfügbar!'
  mycontent[1] = 'Jetzt schnell sein! Nur noch 6 Artikel verfügbar!'
  mycontent[2] = 'Jetzt schnell sein! Nur noch 5 Artikel verfügbar!'
  mycontent[3] = 'Jetzt schnell sein! Nur noch 4 Artikel verfügbar!'

  var i = 0

  function altercontent() {
    dcontent.innerHTML = mycontent[i];
    i = (i == mycontent.length - 1) ? 0 : i + 1
    setTimeout("altercontent()", 1000)
  }

  window.onload = altercontent
</script>
```

Comment: So do not call it? Some reason you loop back to the start....

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`? It will end at 4(your last item) and still keeping the 1-second delay effect

Comment: I have tried to set it to setInterval, but once it finished at 4 it starts glitching and moves the numbers up and down.

Answer (score 0):

use something like

> var yourInterval = setInterval(fn,time);

and the run below statement on some condition such as if(i<4)

> clearInterval(yourInterval);

Above will stop it once it encounters clearInterval();

Read more about it here [Window clearInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)